# Storing data for a POST request in href - bad practice?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js

I'm writing a node.js app and am a bit concerned about how I'm building post data to send to the server. For example, when I want to delete a data item, I put the id of said item in the href attribute:

```
<a class='delete' href="1231">Delete this data</a>
<!-- href is based on a variable I'm pulling from the server -->
```

When that link is clicked, I prevent default actions and then run an ajax request:

```
//On click + ajax
body.on('click', '.delete', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/admin/report/detail/delete',
    data: {id: $(this).attr('href')},
    success: function(){
        //Success message
    },
    error: function(){
        //Error message
    }
});
});
```

I'm wondering, is it bad practice to use the href attribute in this manner? If so, what's the best way to store this data?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use data attributes instead. Storing them in the href isn't semantic, what if you want to store IDs sometimes, and other data at other times? You can create as many data attributes as you like, giving them semantic names.

```
<a class="delete" data-id="1231" href="#">
```

Then in your javascript:

```
...
data: { id: $(this).data('id') }
...
```

OR

```
data: { id: $(this).attr('data-id') }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was thinking. Should my href just be a simple '#'?

Comment: Yeah a hash is the most common href for ajax anchors. I always use `#`. You could also use `javascript:;`, but that pollutes your html and is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, you're always going to have to send the ID of the record to be deleted to the server however you do it. Even if you do data attributes, that isn't the issue here, it's you sending the data "through the wire" via AJAX so people can see the ID.

You need to think - okay, this ID can be changed, however clever you are with it, people will find a way to change it and potentially delete different customer IDs... so... **always** make sure you do the relevant security checks **server side** i.e. is the current logged on user able to delete the user ID that is being sent through?

Comment: +1 for this, my answer is all about semantics, but if there are questions regarding security, this answer is spot on.

Comment: and +1 for yours, you understood the question more than I did, I took it in a security context.

Comment: Yeah, I've got authentication in place on the server side. Actually, I'm converting all of these delete request to POST from GET (don't ask me what I was thinking when I first wrote the code).